# How to Edit the Macro that is created using "after Update" option in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a macro using the 'after update' feature in access to capture some fields into table B (from table A) when the date in a particular column in table A is changed. This is working well.

However, I found out that I wanted to copy one more column to the table B from table A when the date is changed. In order to do this, I need to provide another 'Set Field' option to the original macro . But this macro is neither visible in the navigation pane nor in the VBE.

I am a new user to access and VBA.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] then improve your question (e.g show code)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the table in design mode.

from the ribbon, you can use this dialog:
[image]

If there is a existing macro, say like before change, then you see in the above list that the given  macro will be "highlighed".